# Can you not encfs mount within an existing encfs mount?

Tags: ubuntu, fuse

Let's say that you mounted encfs:

```
 encfs ~/cryptfoo ~/foo
```

Then try to create another encfs inside the mount point:

```
 encfs ~/cryptfoo2 ~/foo/foo2
```

It will fail.

Why does this occur?  I am using Ubuntu 10.04. My encfs is version 1.5. Does this have something to do with fuse?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me if I mount the first encfs with `-o allow_other`, and the second one with `-o nonempty`. You may need to add `user_allow_other` to `/etc/fuse.conf` and add your user to the `fuse` group if you're not doing this as root. This is with encfs 1.5.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 in pre-configured paranoia mode.